# Ошибка компиляции "fatal error RW130 ... Unable to open"

Tags: c++, компилятор

Хочу скомпилировать файл EASY.CPP с таким кодом:

```
 #include <iostream.h>

 void main(void)    
 {
     cout << "Программировать на C++ просто!";
 }
```

Выдает ошибку:

> `Transfer  1:  RC : fatal error RW130: EASY.EXE: Unable to open`

Прошу помочь.

Comment: ну во первых нет using namespace std...<br>
И чем вы компилируете то?<br><br>
PS: На С++ программировать нифига не просто xD

Comment: я по книге С++ хочу создать.Компилирую Borland C++ версия 3.1

Comment: >ну во первых нет using namespace std

 Не нужно, так как iostream.h - это старый заголовочный файл, не использующий пространства имён.

 Кстати, здесь используется void main(), который не все компиляторы поддерживают. Попробуй int main() с "return 0;" в конце перед закрывающей фигурной скобкой.

 Ещё, эта программа, даже если скомпилируется, не выведет текст по-русски.

Comment: \*facepalm\*  
так как iostream.h это старый заголовочный файл, то советую переписать программу с такими изменениями:  
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    cout << "";
    return 0;
    }

Comment: Вопрос то про "EASY.EXE: Unable to open"

Comment: ответ уже дан.  
если эта программа больше нигде не запущена, то советую скомпилировать без запуска и выполнить программу через систему.  
ЗЫ  
с другими программами тоже так?

Comment: я попробую поработать на книжке Дейтеля.

Answer (score 3):

Предыдущая версия программы где-то запущена и компилятор не может ее перезаписать?